# submit complex model with prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'd like to know your opinion about this way used to submit complex models in MVC

For example, if I have a complex model like this:

```
public class TOIFormDTO
{
     public TradeFormDTO Trade { get; set; }
     public OrderFormDTO Order { get; set; }
     public ItemFormDTO Item { get; set; }

     public TOIFormDTO() {
         Trade = new TradeFormDTO();
         Order = new OrderFormDTO();
         Item = new ItemFormDTO();
     }
}
```

And, I bind it to the view in the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveTOI", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "FormTOI" }))
{

    <div id="tabs" style="width:1100px; height:500px">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabTrade">Trade</a></li>

            <li><a href="#tabOrder">Order</a></li>

            <li><a href="#tabItem">Item</a></li>
        </ul>


         <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <div id="tabTrade">
                @Html.PartialForCustomPrefix(model => model.Trade, "~/Views/Trade/Trade.cshtml", "Trade")
            </div>

            <div id="tabOrder" style="display: none">
                @Html.PartialForCustomPrefix(model => model.Order, "~/Views/Order/Order.cshtml", "Order")
            </div>

            <div id="tabItem">
                @Html.PartialForCustomPrefix(model => model.Item, "~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", "Item")
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

By putting a prefix this way:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialForCustomPrefix<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName, string CustomPrefix)
{


    object model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model;
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo
        {
            HtmlFieldPrefix = CustomPrefix
        }
    };

    return helper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);

}
```

This way, when the form is submitted the model is correctly 'recognized' by the action:

```
public ActionResult SaveTOI(TOIFormDTO toiToSave)
{

}
```

Do you think this is a good way to procede, is it solid?
Or do you recognized some potential failure?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? asp.net MVC handles complex model binding.

Comment: Do you mean that it works without using prefix?

Comment: Is there an easier way to post  the form binded to the model in the example?

Comment: Why would you need a custom prefix?

Comment: Because without custom prefix model binding failed, but maybe there was another error. So it is useless to put prefix?

Comment: You don't need a custom prefix. Model binding works for complex models. Can you post the code that fails?